# how to detect model deadlock in Java

Tags: java, deadlock

how to I can write program to model detection?

list of processes, resources, requests and releases:

```
A req R
A req S
A rel R
A rel S
B req S
B req R
B rel S
B rel R
```

Ordering withing a process can't be rearranged (A must always request R before it can request S in the example above), however orderings across processes can be rearranged (B can request S and R before A requests R)

Each ordering will be output with a header, the ordering, and an indication if the order
causes a deadlock or not.

so, how can I sorting all possible orderings of resource request/releases?

**Test Case Inputs :-**

Case 1 :-

```
A req R A req S A rel R A rel S B req S B req T B rel S B rel T C req T 
C req R C rel T C rel R
```

Case 2 :-

```
A req R A req S A rel R A rel S B req T B rel T C req S C rel S D req U 
D req S D req T D rel U D rel S D rel T E req T E req V E rel T E rel V 
F req W F req S F rel W F rel S G req V G req U G rel V G rel U
```

I **need guidance from Stack Community** to solve this problem. So please help me. Thank you...

---

see below source code

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SortStr {

    public static Set<String> permutations = new HashSet<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        List<String> processes = List.of("A req R", "A req S", "A rel R", "A rel S", "B req S", "B req R", "B rel S", "B rel R");
        // List<String> processes = List.of("A req R", "A req S", "A rel R", "A rel S", "B req S", "B req T", "B rel S", "B rel T", "C req T", "C req R", "C rel T", "C rel R");
        Map<String, List<String>> grouped = processes.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy( s -> s.substring(0, 1) ) );
    
        String order = processes.stream().map( s -> s.substring(0, 1) ).collect( Collectors.joining() );
        permutations(order);
    
        int key = 0;
        try{
            String filename= "MyFile.txt";
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filename,true); //the true will append the new data

            for (String o : permutations) {

                Map<Character, Iterator<String>> iterators = grouped.entrySet().stream().collect( 
                    Collectors.toMap( 
                        e->e.getKey().charAt(0), 
                        e-> e.getValue().iterator() 
                    ) 
                );

                String s = "ORDER "+ ++key + " : ";
                Map<String, Boolean> isResourceUsed = new HashMap<>();
                boolean deadlock = false;

                for( char c: o.toCharArray() ){ 
                    // s += iterators.get(c).next() + ", ";
                    // System.out.print( iterators.get(c).next() + ", ");

                    String pro = iterators.get(c).next();
                    String process = pro.substring(0, 1);
                    boolean isRequest = pro.substring(2,5).equals("req");
                    String resource = pro.substring(6,7);

                    if (isRequest) {
                        if (isResourceUsed.containsKey(process) && isResourceUsed.get(process) == true) {
                            deadlock = true;
                            // break;
                        }
                        else {
                            isResourceUsed.put(process, true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (isResourceUsed.containsKey(process)) {
                            isResourceUsed.put(process, false);
                        }
                    }
                    if (deadlock) {
                        s += " DEADLOCK !";
                        break;
                        // System.out.println("deadlock");
                    }
                    else {
                        s += pro +", ";
                        // System.out.println("no deadlock");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(s);
                fw.write(s + "\n"); //appends the string to the file
                System.out.println(); 
            }
            fw.close();
        } catch(IOException ioe){
            System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void permutations(String s) { permutation("", s); }

    private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
        int n = str.length();
        if (n == 0) {
            permutations.add(prefix);
        } else {
            Set<Character> checked = new HashSet<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                Character c = str.charAt(i);
                if( checked.contains(c) ) continue;
                permutation(prefix + c, str.substring(0, i)  + str.substring(i+1, n));
                checked.add(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

see above source code it **prints wrong output** about the order
causes a deadlock or not.

Comment: Thank you for responding to me. can you tell me how can I sorting all possible orderings of resource request/releases?

Comment: Do you have  any code that shows you've started to solve this problem?

Comment: not at moment. So I need guidance about how can I achieve possible ordering of resources. req/rel

Comment: You've gotta simplify this question. You should have at least two example process lists. One should have a deadlock and one shouldn't. Then you should have your code that attempts to find a deadlock. You should have an example process list that your code fails on.

Comment: Here is an example. Is this a deadlock `List.of( "A req R", "A req S", "A rel R", "B req S",   "A rel S", "B req R", "B rel S", "B rel R" );` I would say no. It would stop running because `B` will request `S` before before `S` is released. That is not a deadlock though.

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this (depending on your exact requirements, you probably need to add some logic):

```
    String case1 = "A req R A req S A rel R A rel S B req S B req T B rel S B rel T C req T C req R C rel T C rel R";
    String case2 = "A req R A req S A rel R A rel S B req T B rel T C req S C rel S D req U "
            + "D req S D req T D rel U D rel S D rel T E req T E req V E rel T E rel V "
            + "F req W F req S F rel W F rel S G req V G req U G rel V G rel U";
    String input = case1;
    boolean deadlock = false;
    
    Map<String, Boolean> isResourceUsed = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (int i=0; i<input.length()-7; i+=8) {
        String str = input.substring(i, i+7);
        String process = str.substring(0, 1);
        boolean isRequest = str.substring(2,5).equals("req");
        String resource = str.substring(6,7);
        
        if (isRequest) {
            if (isResourceUsed.containsKey(process) && isResourceUsed.get(process) == true) {
                deadlock = true;
                break;
            }
            else {
                isResourceUsed.put(process, true);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (isResourceUsed.containsKey(process)) {
                isResourceUsed.put(process, false);
            }
        }
        if (deadlock) {
            System.out.println("deadlock");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("no deadlock");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time & giving response to me. but can you tell me how can I sorting all possible orderings of resource request/releases ?

Comment: This seems to assume a "deadlock" is when one task wants a resource, that is held by another task. That isn't really a deadlock, because the resource could be released. A deadlock is when the resources cannot be released because two tasks hold the complement resrouces. eg A has R and wants S but B has S and wants R. In that case neither A nor B can ever acquire the resource necessary to release the one they hold.

Comment: hey I updated my source code. it prints wrong output about the order 
causes a deadlock or not. can you check it?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a set of actions that cannot change order.

```
List<String> A = List.of("A req R", "A req S", "A rel R", "A rel S");
List<String> B = List.of("B req S", "B req R", "B rel S", "B rel R");
```

Now you create a list of the processes.

```
List<String> processes = new ArrayList<>();

processes.addAll(A);
processes.addAll(B);
```

Then you check processes for deadlock. We can create a method for that.

```
boolean checkForDeadlock( List<String> processes);
```

1st problem. You need to generate all of the permutations.

```
a, a, a, a, b, b, b, b
a, a, a, b, a, b, b, b
...
```

You see there are a lot of possibilities. You could write a 4x nested loop.

```
List<String> processes = new ArrayList<>(B);
for( int i = 0; i<5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<=i; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k<=j; k++){
            for(int m = 0; m<=k; m++){
             processes.add( m, A.get(0) );
             processes.add(1 + k, A.get(1));
             processes.add(2 + j, A.get(2));
             processes.add(3 + i, A.get(3));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then there is the dead lock check. A deadlock happens when A holds R and B holds S.

```
int aqr = processes.indexOf("A req R");
int bqr = processes.indexOf("B req R");
int alr = processes.indexOf("A rel R");
if( aqr < bqr && alr > bqr){
    //possible deadlock.
    int aqs = processes.indexOf("A req S");
    int bqs = processes.indexOf("B req S");
    
    if( ars > brs ){
        //A requests S after B has acquired S
        return true;
        //we don't need to see if B has released S, because
        //because we know B has not acquired R yet.
    }
}
return false;
```

Here is the very specific first example. The second example you'll have to 1. Generalize the permutations to more than just A and B species. 2. Generalize the resource acquisition to handle cyclic dependencies. eg D has U needs T; E has T needs V, G has V needs U.

As a hint for your second example. Single locks are irrelevant, so cross out B and C. A only shares one resource so it can be crossed out. F only shares one resource so cross it out. So your only possible deadlocks are between D E and G

This is more than just a homework assignment, this is a full on project. You should reallly break it down into individual problems and ask those.

Comment: hey I have added my source code for generate all permutations. please checkout it. now how can I check `Ordering withing a process can't be rearranged (A must always request R before it can request S in the example above), however orderings across processes can be rearranged (B can request S and R before A requests R)` this criteria during permutations generate. please guide me. & tell me if I made mistake in my source code

Comment: @HarshPatel This is the problem answering questions like this. I write up a big answer with details and such, then you write something completely tangent pretty much asking a completely new question. You should probably clean up your question and focus solely on the permutations and leave out anything about deadlocks.

Comment: I open up new separate question about permutation generation  https://stackoverflow.com/q/75587615/14344959 can you help me? I tried a lot but i can't achieve this

Comment: as you guide, all possible permutation generate perfectly. but now when I tries to check each order causes a deadlock or not. it prints wrong output of deadlock please tell me if i made mistakes