# how to generate all possible ordering permutations of given list of string in java

Tags: java, permutation

list of processes, resources, requests and releases:

```
A req R
A req S
A rel R
A rel S
B req S
B req R
B rel S
B rel R
```

Ordering withing a process can't be rearranged (A must always request R before it can request S in the example above), however orderings across processes can be rearranged (B can request S and R before A requests R)

```
package Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Stack;

public class SortStr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();

        List<String> A = List.of("A req R", "A req S", "A rel R", "A rel S");
        List<String> B = List.of("B req S", "B req R", "B rel S", "B rel R");
        s.addAll(A);
        s.addAll(B);

        /* List<String> A = List.of("A");
        List<String> B = List.of("1");
        List<String> C = List.of("X");

        s.addAll(A);
        s.addAll(B);
        s.addAll(C); */

        Map<Integer, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
        permutations(s, new Stack<String>(), s.size(), result);

        result.forEach((key, value) -> 
            System.out.println("ORDER " + key + " : " + value)
        );
    }

    public static void permutations(Set<String> items, Stack<String> permutation, int size,
            Map<Integer, List<String>> result) {

        /* permutation stack has become equal to size that we require */
        if (permutation.size() == size) {
            /* print the permutation */
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(permutation.toArray(new String[0])));

            /* add the permutation in the result */
            Integer key = (result.size() > 0) ? result.size() + 1 : 0;
            result.put(key, Arrays.asList(permutation.toArray(new String[0])));
        }

        /* items available for permutation */
        String[] availableItems = items.toArray(new String[0]);
        for (String i : availableItems) {
            /* add current item */
            permutation.push(i);

            /* remove item from available item set */
            items.remove(i);

            /* pass it on for next permutation */
            permutations(items, permutation, size, result);

            /* pop and put the removed item back */
            items.add(permutation.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

Above Program generate all the possible sorting permutations. but my conditional criteria is  `a process can't be rearranged (A must always request R before it can request S in the example above), however orderings across processes can be rearranged (B can request S and R before A requests R)`

so, how can I sorting all possible orderings of resource request/releases?

**Output Result what I want:-**

```
ORDER 1: A req R, A req S, A rel R, A rel S, B req S, B req R, B rel S, B rel R
ORDER 2: A req R, A req S, A rel R, B req S, A rel S, B req R, B rel S, B rel R
...
ORDER X: A req R, B req S, A req S, B req R ...
```

---

**Test Case Inputs :-**

Case 1 :-

```
A req R A req S A rel R A rel S B req S B req T B rel S B rel T C req T 
C req R C rel T C rel R
```

Case 2 :-

```
A req R A req S A rel R A rel S B req T B rel T C req S C rel S D req U 
D req S D req T D rel U D rel S D rel T E req T E req V E rel T E rel V 
F req W F req S F rel W F rel S G req V G req U G rel V G rel U
```

I tried a lot but I can't
So, Please guide me to achieve this permutations generation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should start by organizing your data a bit better, then you can use the permutation algorithm.

```
List<String> processes = List.of("A req R", "A req S", "A rel R", "A rel S", "B req S", "B req R", "B rel S", "B rel R");
```

First

```
Map<String, List<String>> grouped = processes.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy( s -> s.substring(0, 1) ) );
```

Now you have a collection of a list of processes that you're not going to re-arrange.

```
String order = processes.stream().map( s -> s.substring(0, 1) ).collect( Collectors.joining() );
```

Now order is a string of the process names, "AAAABBBB". You can create all the permutations of this string. Your algorithm should work, it might produce duplicates so either store the results in a Set so it only keeps unique values.

This version below should only generate unique permutations.

```
List<String> permutations = new HashSet<>();

void permutations(String s){
    permutation("", String str)
}

void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 0) permutations.add(prefix);
    else {
        Set<Character> checked = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            Character c = str.charAt(i);
            if( checked.contains(c) ) continue;
            permutation(prefix + c, str.substring(0, i)  + str.substring(i+1, n));
            checked.add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

The last step is to get the processes back.

```
String o = ...; //one entry taken from the list of all permutations.

Map<Character, Iterator<String>> iterators = grouped.entrySet().stream().collect( 
    Collectors.toMap( 
        e->e.getKey().charAt(0), 
        e-> e.getValue().iterator() 
    ) 
);
for( char c: o.toCharArray() ){ 
    System.out.print( iterators.get(c).next() + ", ");
}
System.out.println();
```

That gives me.

> A req R, A req S, A rel R, A rel S, B req S, B req R, B rel S, B rel R,
> A req R, A req S, A rel R, B req S, A rel S, B req R, B rel S, B rel R,
> A req R, A req S, A rel R, B req S, B req R, A rel S, B rel S, B rel R,
> ...
> B req S, B req R, B rel S, A req R, B rel R, A req S, A rel R, A rel S,
> B req S, B req R, B rel S, B rel R, A req R, A req S, A rel R, A rel S,